# Jest test suite failed to `import *as vscode from 'vscode' in typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

I have a simple function in simaple.ts package. In this package, I imported vscode: `import * as vscode from 'vscode'`.
I'm trying to test this function:

```
export function simple(name1:string) {
if (os.platform() !== 'win32') {
        return name1;
    }
    return name1.replace(/\\/g, '/');
}
```

This function has nothing to do with vscode imported here but other functions in this package do.

Then in my test package `simple.test.ts`, I have

```
import { simple } from '../src/simple';
describe('Test simple', () => {
it('Testing simple()', () => {
    expect(simple('\\Users\\admin\\Downloads')).toEqual('/Users/admin/Downloads');
});
});
```

This is the error I'm getting.[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvbSv.png when I run `npm test`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path it’s referencing is incorrect and can’t be loaded. Although that particular function doesn’t import vs ode, typescript still has to compile the project and resolve all the paths. Check the validity of the import it’s complaining about in the error message

Comment: I think the path is valid because  some of the functions in `vscode` module have been used in 'utils.ts' without any error. It seems like the test suite is trying to import `vscode` from `utils.ts` which got me confused because `utils.ts` package is the one importing `vscode` module.